# How can I add button at the bottom of the screen having a recycler View. so that the button don't hide the last element of recycler view

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-button

I want to add the button which will only be shown at when any item of recycler view is checked and hide it when uncheck.
The button should not hide the last element of recycler view.
I tried this code but when I make the button visible (by selecting an item of recycler view) and scroll to the bottom of the recycler view it overlap the last element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity.RestaurantMenuActivity">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/menu_header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:elevation="6dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/header_ll_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_restaurant_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="8.2"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingStart="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="6dp"
                android:text="Sample restaurant name"
                android:textColor="@color/Black"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_restaurant_fav"
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1.8"
                android:padding="6dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_fav" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_menu_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/header_ll_layout"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_list"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingStart="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="6dp"
            android:paddingEnd="16dp"
            android:paddingBottom="6dp"
            android:text="@string/menu"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bt_goto_cart"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/green"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="3dp"
            android:paddingBottom="3dp"
            android:text="SampleGOTOcart"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            tools:visibility="visible" />
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/menu_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/tv_menu_title"
            android:background="@color/white" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/menu_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bt_goto_cart"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv_menu_title"
        android:background="@color/white" />
```

Comment: This works like perfectly for me only thing I need to do is keep the Button(bt_goto_cart) visibility to GONE.